# ¿como obtener los nombres de los días de la semana y las fechas de todo el mes?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Buenas estoy trabajando con las Data tables de jquery, este es mi código
tengo como variables globales mi tabla y la fecha

```
var table_bdi=null;

var fecha = new Date();


var maximo_mes=new Date(fecha.getFullYear(), fecha.getMonth() +mesel, 0).getDate();
for (var i =0; i<=maximo_mes-1; i++) {

        if([i]>=data.length-1)
        {
            dataset[i] = [];
      dataset[i].push(cantidad++);     
      dataset[i].push(dias_mes([i])+'-'+$('#mes_actual').val()+'-'+fecha.getFullYear());
      dataset[i].push('0');
      dataset[i].push('0');
      dataset[i].push('0');
      dataset[i].push('0');

        }else{

      dataset[i] = [];   
      dataset[i].push(cantidad++);  
      dataset[i].push(dias_mes([i])+'-'+$('#mes_actual').val()+'-'+fecha.getFullYear());
      dataset[i].push(dia_nombre([i]));
      dataset[i].push(data[i].ase);
      dataset[i].push(data[i].a);
      dataset[i].push(data[i].s);

      }
    }

console.log(dataset);

  if(table_bdi) {
    table_bdi.destroy();
    $('#table_1').empty();
    table_bdi = null;
  }

  if (table_bdi == null) {
      table_bdi = $('#table_1').DataTable({
        data: dataset,
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [{
        extend: 'excelHtml5', className: 'button green button-min' , text: 'EXCEL'},
       {extend: 'pdfHtml5', className: 'button red button-min' , text: 'PDF'}

            ],

function dias_mes(i){


    let numero = $('#mes_actual').val();
    numero=Number(numero)-1;
    i=Number(i)+1;

    return new Date(fecha.getFullYear(), fecha.getMonth() + numero, i).getDate();
  }
```

cuando cambio de mes con change le mando el mes a `mesel` y ya me da el los días en numero del mes entonces recorro, la duda que tengo es que cuando selecciono un mes no me da las fecha del mes correcto `dia_nombre([i])` tengo algo así en esa función, pero ya no se que mandarle, algún consejo? solamente el mes de febrero me da bien pero si quiero enero no me da 31 días me da 30 y el nombre del día no coincide

```
 function dia_nombre(i)
      {


   let dias = ['Domingo','Lunes','Martes','Miércoles','Jueves','Viernes','Sábado'];
    let numero = $('#mes_actual').val();
    numero=Number(numero)-1;

    i=Number(i)+1;

    let dia = new Date(fecha.getFullYear(), fecha.getMonth() + numero, i).getDay();

    return dias[dia];
      }
```

pongo una imagen de lo que quiero que se mire mi tabla de jquery 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Algo así es lo que quiero hacer

Y asi se mira en mi tabla cuando selecciono enero no coincide con el nombre del dia y ademas cuando llega al dia 30 de enero pasa denuevo a 1 de enero envez de 31 de enero

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Que te muestra la consola?

Answer (score 0):

Sólo veo un error en tu función dia_nombre(), define `var fecha = new Date();` al inicio de ella.

Cuando trabajes con JavaScript, procura estar al tanto de los eventos en consola (herramientas para desarrollador), te ayudará a solventar muchos errores de sintaxis, estructura, etc.. por ti mismo.

Tu función quedaría asi:

```
function dia_nombre(i)
  {
    var fecha = new Date();
    let dias = ['Domingo','Lunes','Martes','Miércoles','Jueves','Viernes','Sábado'];

    return dias[fecha.getDay()];
  }
```

**¿Qué es la consola de JavaScript?:**

https://norfipc.com/inf/como-usar-consola-javascript-navegador-web.php

Comment: se me olvido mencionar,  var fecha = new Date(); la tengo declarada como variable global ya que trabajare mucho con fechas es por eso que no la puse, disculpa se me paso mencionar, nadamas que si la dejo asi siempre me va a imprimir martes, actualizo cambios que e realizado

Comment: Descuida, ¿ya intentaste en tu función dia_nombre() retornar: ``return dias[i];``?

Comment: actualize la funcion hice lo mismo que mi funcion dias_mes y solo le cambie envez de getDate a getDay